# What is MainActivity$1$1

Tags: java, android, exception

I am developping an Android app and I catch the log error:

```
05-11 12:45:29.623  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-11 12:45:29.623  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 12:45:29.623  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-11 12:45:29.623  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ at focalys.android_avh.connection.Connection.call(Connection.java:85)
05-11 12:45:29.623  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ at focalys.android_avh.connection.Connection.onPostExecute(Connection.java:70)
05-11 12:45:29.623  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ at focalys.android_avh.connection.Connection.onPostExecute(Connection.java:19)
05-11 12:45:29.623  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
05-11 12:45:29.623  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
05-11 12:45:29.633  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
05-11 12:45:29.633  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-11 12:45:29.633  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
05-11 12:45:29.633  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
05-11 12:45:29.633  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 12:45:29.633  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-11 12:45:29.633  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
05-11 12:45:29.633  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
05-11 12:45:29.633  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-11 12:45:29.633  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected receiver of type focalys.android_avh.connection.MainActivity$1$1, but got java.lang.Boolean
05-11 12:45:29.633  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 12:45:29.633  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-11 12:45:29.633  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ at focalys.android_avh.connection.AvhWS$1.call(AvhWS.java:44)
05-11 12:45:29.633  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ at focalys.android_avh.connection.AvhWS$1.auth(AvhWS.java:37)
05-11 12:45:29.633  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ ... 16 more
```

I would like to focus on the line :
`05-11 12:45:29.633  27110-27110/focalys.avh_android W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected receiver of type focalys.android_avh.connection.MainActivity$1$1`, but got `java.lang.Boolean`
because I don't understand what is `MainActivity$1$1`. What is it supposed to represent ? Is it an object, a method ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: anonymous inner class(es)

Comment: an anonymous inner class inside an anonymous inner class

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found my problem. I was actually trying to make callbacks but there is a more simple way to do it by using and interface like in the example:

http://www.justinmccandless.com/blog/Setting+Up+a+Callback+Function+in+Android

Hope it will help ! 
Thanks for your answers anyway.